# composer install error with php 8.0.17 and drupal 9

Tags: php, composer-php, drupal-9

I am getting very unusual issue. I have a drupal 9.2.18 site working with php 7.4
I want to update to php 8, initially i am trying to do at 8.0 instead of 8.1.
When I do `composer update` it upgrade/downgrade few plugins due to php version check, it also updated composer api version to 2.3.0. Composer update works fine at my local instance. After that when I run `composer install` on my local it works fine as well.

However when I upload code on eks server and build process start, `composer install` fails. I troubleshooted and found the reason that vendor folder doesn't exists on server, composer install download all plugins from lock file and fails after line Updating dependencies.
I tried same scenario on local and able to reproduce the error.
PHP 8.0.17
Composer 2.3.5

Steps below

`composer update` // works fine

`rm -rf vendor` // remove vendor to simulate server

`composer install` // fails as below error

`PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule2Literals::getLiterals() must be compatible with Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule::getLiterals(): array in /cms/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule2Literals.php on line 48`

`Fatal error: Declaration of Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule2Literals::getLiterals() must be compatible with Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule::getLiterals(): array in /cms/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule2Literals.php on line 48`

**Edited:**
Composer version is 2.2.12, Now got this error

Running composer update to apply merge settings
Gathering patches for root package.

> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of React\Promise\RejectedPromise::then(?callable $onFulfilled = null, ?callable $onRejected = null, ?callable $onProgress = null) must be compatible with React\Promise\PromiseInterface::then($fulfilledHandler = null, $errorHandler = null, $progressHandler = null) in /var/www/d9/vendor/react/promise/src/RejectedPromise.php on line 21

Fatal error: Declaration of React\Promise\RejectedPromise::then(?callable $onFulfilled = null, ?callable $onRejected = null, ?callable $onProgress = null) must be compatible with React\Promise\PromiseInterface::then($fulfilledHandler = null, $errorHandler = null, $progressHandler = null) in /var/www/d9/vendor/react/promise/src/RejectedPromise.php on line 21

composer.json as below, few lines are from our repo like patch and contrib_override modules but those can be skipped as problem is not related to those

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
          "type": "package",
          "package": {
            "name": "ckeditor/find",
            "version": "4.14.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "extra": {
              "installer-name": "ckeditor/plugins/find"
            },
            "dist": {
              "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/find/releases/find_4.14.1.zip",
              "type": "zip"
            }
          }
        },
                {
                        "type": "package",
                        "package": {
                                "name": "ckeditor/liststyle",
                                "version": "4.8.0",
                                "type": "drupal-library",
                                "extra": {
                                        "installer-name": "ckeditor/plugins/liststyle"
                                },
                                "dist": {
                                        "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/liststyle/releases/liststyle_4.8.0.zip",
                                        "type": "zip"
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "type": "package",
                        "package": {
                                "name": "ckeditor/pastefromword",
                                "version": "4.15.1",
                                "type": "drupal-library",
                                "extra": {
                                        "installer-name": "ckeditor/plugins/pastefromword"
                                },
                                "dist": {
                                        "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/pastefromword/releases/pastefromword_4.15.1.zip",
                                        "type": "zip"
                                }
                        }
                }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0",
        "ckeditor/liststyle": "4.8.0",
        "ckeditor/pastefromword": "4.15.1",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.2",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.2",
        "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^4.24",
        "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.1",
        "drupal/ckeditor_liststyle": "^1.3",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.2",
        "drupal/console": "^1.9.7",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "9.2.18",
        "drupal/core-dev": "9.2.18",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "9.2.18",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "9.2.18",
        "drupal/csv_serialization": "^1.4",
        "drupal/date_popup_timepicker": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.1",
        "drupal/duration_field": "^2.0",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.0",
        "drupal/eva": "^2.0",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.16",
        "drupal/link_iframe_formatter": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/meta_position": "^1.0",
        "drupal/optional_end_date": "^1.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6",
        "drupal/s3fs": "^3.0",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.6",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.12",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
        "drupal/video_embed_vzaar": "^1.0",
        "drupal/view_custom_table": "^1.3",
        "drupal/view_unpublished": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/views_autocomplete_filters": "^1.3",
        "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_ef_fieldset": "^1.4",
        "drupal/weight": "^3.1",
        "drupal/workflow": "^1.1",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.4",
        "smalot/pdfparser": "^0.16.2",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.1",
        "wa72/htmlpagedom": "1.3.*",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.2",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpspec/prophecy-phpunit": "^2",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
            "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true,
            "kylekatarnls/update-helper": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
          "include": [
            "web/modules/contrib_override/*/composer.json",
            "web/modules/contrib_override/printable/modules/printable_pdf/composer.json",
            "web/modules/custom/*/composer.json"
          ],
          "recurse": true,
          "merge-dev": true
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core" : {
              "Core fields delta not consider as change" : "web/patches/core-fields-delta-not-consider-as-change.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. Do you by any chance use an outdated version of `composer/installers`? What does `composer why composer/composer`  yield?

Comment: You need to run `composer self-update`. This may need to be run as su/sudo

Comment: `composer why composer/composer` gives `drupal/core-dev  9.2.18  requires  composer/composer (^2.0.2)` @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

Got some clue, If i not allow this plugin to make changes then my problem get resolved, now composer install work fine even after removing vendor folder

`kylekatarnls/update-helper contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins Do you trust "kylekatarnls/update-helper" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] n`

Though Not sure what this plugin update